# Retain textbox content after hiding and re-showing the form

Tags: c#

I'm beginner in c#. I have form1 with some textboxes that user fills and goes to form2 with a Next button which hides form1 and opens form2. Also form2 has a Previous button which hides form2 and reopens form1. (In situation that user noticed that made a mistake in form1 and wants to edit it). But when form1 opens all of the textboxes are clear. How I can retain contents of textboxes when hided and re-showed?

Comment: You, probably, `Close` the form and then create and `Show` it again instead of `Hide` it. In order to delect the cause if nisbehaviour, please, provide the *relevant code*

Comment: Please add code so that your issue comes across clearer.

Comment: When form1 RE-OPENS, all of the textboxes is clear? is that what you want?

Comment: I want all of the filled txtboxes not to be cleared. Becuase the user going to edit some of them not re-fill all of them. But when I re-show the form, normally all of the txtboxes became cleared and user should fill all of them again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Any of the statement given below to clear the text of the text box on button click:

```
    private void PrevButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       textBox1.Clear(); 
       textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
       textBox3.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to clear txtboxes. I want to txtboxes not to be cleared after hide and re-show the form.

Comment: then you have to save the value.